# Spring. Отправка email (сервер mail.ru) с вложением. Проблема с названиями файлов

Tags: java, spring, кодировка, sendmail, javamail

Использую вот такой код для отправки сообщений пользователям через сервер mail.ru:

```
    package com.art.func;

    import com.art.config.AppSecurityConfig;
    import com.art.model.Users;
    import com.art.model.supporting.GenericResponse;
    import com.art.model.supporting.SendingMail;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl;
    import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

    import javax.mail.Authenticator;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeUtility;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Properties;

    @org.springframework.stereotype.Service
    public class PersonalMailService {
        private static final String ENCODING = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name();

        public GenericResponse sendEmails(Users user, SendingMail sendingMail, String username, String pwd,
                                          String who, List<MultipartFile> file){
            GenericResponse response = new GenericResponse();
            JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

            String fileName = "mail.ru.properties";
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            InputStream input;
            try{
                input = AppSecurityConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
                prop.load(input);
            }catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            //Using mail.ru
            mailSender.setHost(prop.getProperty("mail.host"));
            mailSender.setPort(Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("mail.port")));

            mailSender.setUsername(username);
            mailSender.setPassword(pwd);
            mailSender.setProtocol(prop.getProperty("mail.protocol"));

            Authenticator auth = new MyAuthenticator(mailSender.getUsername(), mailSender.getPassword());
    /* НОВОЕ */
System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodefilename", "true");
        System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");
/* НОВОЕ */
            Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.transport.protocol", prop.getProperty("mail.protocol"));
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty("mail.port")));
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.host", prop.getProperty("mail.host"));
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.auth"));
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.debug", prop.getProperty("mail.debug"));
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", prop.getProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable"));
            javaMailProperties.put("mail.mime.charset", ENCODING);
            Session session = Session.getInstance(javaMailProperties, auth);

            mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties);
            mailSender.setSession(session);

            mailSender.send(mimeMessage -> {
                MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(
                        mimeMessage, true, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name());
                messageHelper.setTo(user.getEmail());
                messageHelper.setSubject(sendingMail.getSubject());
                messageHelper.setText(sendingMail.getBody());
                messageHelper.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username, who));
                file.forEach(f -> {
                    String attachName = f.getOriginalFilename();
                    if (!attachName.equals("")) {
                        try{
                            messageHelper.addAttachment(MimeUtility.encodeText(attachName, StandardCharsets
                                    .UTF_8.name(), "B"), f);
                            response.setMessage("Письма успешно отправлены.");
                        } catch (MessagingException e) {
                            response.setError("При отправке писем что-то пошло не так.");
                        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });

            });

            return response;
        }

        class MyAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
            private String user;
            private String password;

            MyAuthenticator(String user, String password) {
                this.user = user;
                this.password = password;
            }

            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                String user = this.user;
                String password = this.password;
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }

        }
```

Тема письма и содержание приходит в верной кодировке. Проблема состоит в том, что если отправляю письмо с вложением файлов (названия на русском) на mail.ru пользователю, то файл приходит с корректным названием (на русском). Если отправляю на gmail.com, то тут 2 варианта. 1. Если просматривать в браузере, то приходит исковерканное название "=_UTF-8_B_0JrQsNC70YzQutGD0LvRj9GC0L7RgCDQtNC 0YXQvtC00L0=_= =_UTF-8_B_0L7RgdGC0Lgg0L3QsCAxMCDQu9C10YIueGxzeA==_=". 2. Если просматриваю через iPhone (стандартное приложение почта), то всё отображается корректно. Не знаю куда копать. 3 дня топчусь на месте.

### UPD:

Ошибка появляется если длина имени файла более 33 знаков (включая "точку" и расширение). По прежнему не пойму где искать. Уменьшать длину названий не вариант. Идеи?

Comment: Могу подтолкнуть прочить [это](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3773901) и поиграться со свойствами как указано по ссылке так : `System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");`  (указать в начале метода)

Comment: @MrFylypenko, спасибо! Вы во второй раз уже даёте правильное направление, благодаря которому мои вопросы решаются! Оформите в виде отдельного ответа, чтобы я мог отметить его решённым. В коде первого поста можно увидеть добавленные строки, которые решили проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решения взято [отсюда](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3773901) .

> MIME spec говорит о закодированном слове: Закодированное слово
>   может содержать не более 75 символов, включая `charset, encoding,
>   encoded text, and delimiters.` Если необходимо кодировать больше
>   текста, чем будет помещено в кодированное слово из 75 символов, может
>   использоваться несколько закодированных слов (разделенных
>   пространством CRLF).

Т.е. название файла по умолчанию кодируется согласно MIME спецификации и поддерживается **не всеми** почтовыми программами.

Для использования нестандартной MIME-кодировки для имен файлов необходимо установить свойства системы  "mail.mime.encodefilename" в "true" и "mail.mime.encodeparameters" в "false".
В коде это будет выгляеть так:

```
System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodefilename", "true");
System.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "false");
```